# How to use AverageIf worksheet function for calculating average date differences (in case date is filled in)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, array-formulas

I'm making a summary of a list of tasks, and the corresponding dates (start date, first answer date, ...).

It looks more or less like the following:

```
Title    Start date    First answer
Task1     29/06/2018   02/07/2018
Task2     09/05/2018   
Task3     13/06/2018   14/06/2018
```

I would like to calculate the average time, needed for the first answer to be given. In case no first answer is given yet, this entry needs to be ignored in the calculation of the average.

In order to be able to understand the formulas better, I've decided to use names for the headers, like:

```
Name "Header_Title"        has value "Title"
Name "Header_Start_Date"   has value "Start Date"
Name "Header_First_Answer" has value "First answer"
```

Also, the number of entries, defined as `COUNTA(OFFSET(Header_Title;1;0):A1048576)` has a name: `Total_Count`.

Next to that, I've created names for the ranges of the column values:

```
"All_Start_Dates"    is defined as =OFFSET(Header_Start_Date;1;0):OFFSET(Header_Start_Date;Total_Count;0)
"All_First_Answered" is defined as =OFFSET(Header_First_Answer;1;0):OFFSET(Header_First_Answer;Total_Count;0)
```

Explanation : take the first entry under the header (column title) and go to the row, corresponding to the last task.

This makes it very easy to write a formula for calculating the average difference between those date columns:

```
{=AVERAGE(All_First_Answered_Dates-All_Start_Dates)}
// mind the {} for showing this is an array formula
```

Now the problem is: how to use the `AverageIf` worksheet function in order not to take into account the cases where `First answer` is not filled in?
I already tried using `">0"` and `">"&0`, but this does not work, the formulas are said not to be valid:

```
{=AVERAGEIF(All_First_Answered_Dates-All_Start_Dates;">0")}
{=AVERAGEIF(All_First_Answered_Dates-All_Start_Dates;">"&0)}
```

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

P.s.1. As you can see, I'm using cell range `A1048576` as the last entry of column `A`, does anybody know a more elegant way to describe this?
P.s.2. One extra thing, which would make my life easier, is the possibility to see which cells have a name (I was thinking about conditional formatting, but I didn't find the way to do this). Does anybody know if there is a way to highlight individual cells, linked to a name?

Comment: Instead of using `A1048576` - number of entries would be `COUNTA(A:A) - 1`

Comment: Can you add another column at the end which calculates the difference between the 2 dates only if both dates are provided and than take an average of that?

Comment: I think it's true that average(x-y) is the same as average(x)-average(y) as long as x and y are paired, so maybe you could use two averageif's?

Comment: also your defined names can be defined as OFFSET(Header_Start_Date,1,0,Total_Count,1) i.e. from Header Start Date, go down one row and zero columns, then extend the selection by Total_Count rows and one column.

Comment: @Zac: you are right, this is indeed the general way people are working with Excel, but this means that I need to hide columns, which I don't like to do, and array formulas look like a good way to get this done.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to hide that column? It would display valid/useful information

Comment: @BigBen: good idea, but it's not that simple: at the top of my file, I've put the summary, and it might happen that I enter some data/headers there, so those cells must not been taken into account. Therefore I'm starting at a particular cell (A14 in this particular case), going to the end of that column.

Comment: @TomSharpe: unfortunately it's not that simple: indeed `Average(X-Y)=Average(X) - Average(Y)`, but some of the `Y` values need to be disregarded, and I don't know how to find/disregard the corresponding `X` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my suggested answer would be

```
=AVERAGEIF(All_First_Answered,">0")-AVERAGEIF(All_First_Answered,">0",All_Start_Dates)
```

I'm assuming here that all start dates are present but first answered dates may be missing: you could easily add an extra condition for start date if you used AVERAGEIFS. Both parts of the formula include the same conditions so they are working on the same rows.

[image]

The intermediate columns above are just included by way of explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try an array formula.

If you're not familiar with array formulas, the significant difference is you press and hold Ctrl+Shift then hit Enter instead of just pressing Enter. You will see the formula preceded and followed by curly brackets. Do not type those. Those will appear automatically.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(INDIRECT("C14:C"&LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A)))=0,"",INDIRECT("C14:C"&LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A)))-INDIRECT("B14:B"&LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A)))))
```

Comment: I know what an array formula is: I just typed the curly brackets for readability reasons (I don't type them in my formula). As for your formula: I tried it but it gives `#Value` results. By the way, what should the result be?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't see the comment where you're starting at row 14. I've edited the above response to start at row 14 and take into account any rows that might be empty in the middle of your data set.