# Is it possible to use single-cell formulas on arrays in array formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

This is a next question, based on "[How to use AverageIf worksheet function for calculating average date differences (in case date is filled in)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403707/how-to-use-averageif-worksheet-function-for-calculating-average-date-differences/51405456?noredirect=1#comment89806083_51405456)":

Now my boss wants to know, imagine that the empty cells are replaced with `TODAY()`, what effect does this have on the average or maximum values.

I'm trying this, using following formula:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ISBLANK(All_First_Answered_Dates);TODAY()))}
// mind the curly brackets, I'm working with array formulas here.
```

As a result, I get the date of today, which, in my opinion, means the following:
As Excel sees that there are blank cells, somewhere in the mentioned range, he replaces every cell in that range (including the non-empty ones) by `TODAY()`, and obviously the average of a whole list of todays equals today :-)

In case I don't work with an array formula, the result equals 0.
This makes sense: the name `All_First_Answered_Dates` is a range of cells, which Excel can only work with in case of an array formula. Else it's not recognised, so it's not blank, the `IF()` formula yields `FALSE` and the average of `FALSE` is `0`.

Basically, the issue is caused by the formula `ISBLANK(All_First_Answered_Dates;TODAY()'))` where I apply a single cell formula `TODAY()` on an entire range `All_First_Answered_Dates`, all of it in an array formula.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you need your `False`-criteria to return the same range that you are evaluating, i.e.:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ISBLANK(All_First_Answered_Dates);TODAY();All_First_Answered_Dates))}
```

To further explain: For each cell in the range, it is evaluated whether or not the cell is empty (blank). If it is, then a `TODAY()`-value is returned. However, if it is not empty, a blank ("") is returned, as that is what you have as you `Else`-criteria. If instead your `Else`-criteria is the same range, then you will return the cell in that range and it will then be used in the `AVERAGE`-function